# How to install a deprecated deb package from debian repositories

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, downgrade

I'm looking for a way to install apache2-2.2.9-10+lenny4 on a debian lenny which, up to date, only have the apache2-2.2.9-10+lenny6 package.
The reason I have to install the old version is to debug a website on this machine.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to type the following at a root prompt:

1. wget $URL
2. sudo dpkg -i $PACKAGE_FILE --force

Replacing $URL with the url of the package file in the debian repository - which should be obtainable via packages.debian.org/apache2 and $PACKAGE_FILE by the name of the .deb you downloaded in step 1.

Note that this may leave  your machine in a bad state. Messing around with dpkg/apt in this manner is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you, it should be ok for me since the versions I need are not so old.
Have a nice day !